# How can I display target modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I display target modal? when I clicked Alex, I want to show Alex, and When I clicked Nick, need to show Nick. How can i do this, any idea?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "react-modal";

let data = [
  { name: "Alex", age: 25 },
  { name: "Nick", age: 19 },
];

  export const Test = () => {
  const [showModal, displayModal] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const test = (nm) => {
    if (Object.keys(nm).length) {
      setData(nm);
    }
    displayModal(!showModal);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={test}>
        {data.map((nm) => (
          <div key={nm.id}>
            <span>{nm.name}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <Modal isOpen={showModal} onRequestClose={() => displayModal(false)}>
        <div>
          <p>{data.name}</p>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where are `HelpModal` and `HelpDialogStyle` come from? Seems like basically your code should show the modal

Comment: @MoshFeu, Oh, Its styled component

Comment: Got you. Well, Fatemeh Qasemkhani's answer is good

Comment: @MoshFeu, Im getting an error

Comment: Can you elaborate? What error?

Comment: @MoshFeu, I updated code, error is : can't read map

Comment: You shadow `data` (the source array and the hook) . Change `const [data, setData] = useState(null);` to `const [user, setUser] = useState(null);` and call `setUser` instead of `setData`.

Comment: @MoshFeu, thanks for ur answer, but is there better solution?

Comment: What's wrong with this one :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get data in text function, then pass it as props to your modal.

```
const [modalData, setModalData] = useState(null);
const [showModal, displayModal] = useState(false);

const test = nm => {
  if(Object.keys(nm).length) { setModalData(nm); }
  displayModal(!showModal);
};

{data.map((nm) => (
  <div key={nm.id} onClick={() => test(nm)}>
    <span>{nm.name}</span>
  </div>
))}

<HelpModal isOpen={showModal} onRequestClose={() => displayModal(false)}>
    <p>{modalData.name}</p>
    <p>{modalData.age}</p>
</HelpModal>
```

Comment: change data to modalData, thats why there are two data as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "react-modal";

let data = [
  { name: "Alex", age: 25 },
  { name: "Nick", age: 19 },
];

export const Test = () => {
  const [showModal, displayModal] = useState(false);
  const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState(null);

  const openModal = nm => {
    if (Object.keys(nm).length) {
      setSelectedData(nm);
    }
    displayModal(!showModal);
  };
  
  const closeModal = () => {
    displayModal(!showModal);
    setSelectedData(null);
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {data.map((nm) => (
          <div key={nm.id} onClick={() => openModal(nm}>
            <span>{nm.name}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <HelpModal isOpen={showModal} onRequestClose={closeModal}>
        <HelpDialogStyle>
          {
            selectedData &&
            <p>{selectedData.name}</p>
          }
        </HelpDialogStyle>
      </HelpModal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```